# How do tags *actually* work?

Tags: mercurial, vcs-tags

[The docs](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Tag) say all the tags are stored in `.hgtags`, but there's clearly some black magic going on here.

My tags look like this:

```
mbayazit:~/test$ cat .hgtags 
0d80b6ba4ba3b51a44f0f1d339fcac1d4b21f387 stable
c70d8e7e516d8b9e0c520063a575b4acea1b2f94 testtag
0d80b6ba4ba3b51a44f0f1d339fcac1d4b21f387 stable
b1a360af6daf536ddc55b6b50127e88c30a227dc stable
```

If I update to `testtag`,

```
mbayazit:~/test$ hg up testtag
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 2 files removed, 0 files unresolved
```

The tags disappear,

```
mbayazit:~/test$ cat .hgtags 
cat: .hgtags: No such file or directory
```

Because `testtag` is older than the others; why it's out of order I don't know.

But when I try to update to `stable` again,

```
mbayazit:~/test$ hg up stable
3 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
```

It magically works. How is that possible if that tag isn't even in `.hgtags`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The available tags are the union of all the .hgtags in all the heads of your repo.  So to see everything you'd need to see what `.hgtags` looks like in every revision that shows up in `hg heads`.  @black_wizard has a great explanation of why you don't see your tag in `.hgtags` when you update to them, and "the `.hgtags` file is read from the `hg heads`" is why they still work.

Answer (score 5):

In the second section of the official tags [documentation](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Tag) written this statement:

> Updating a working dir to a particular tag will take that directory
>   back to a point **before** the tag itself existed.

For the first time `.hgtags` file is created when you tag particular revision. 
When you update your repository state to this tagged revision, state of your repository is actually right before the `.hgtags` been added to version control.

Here's the example when we add first tag and then update repository state to this tagged revision:

```
PS D:\tagstest> hg init
PS D:\tagstest [default tip]> echo 'Something' > readme.txt
PS D:\tagstest [default ?1 tip]> hg addremove
adding readme.txt
PS D:\tagstest [default +1 tip]> hg ci -m "First commit"
PS D:\tagstest [default tip]> hg tag first
PS D:\tagstest [default tip]> cat .\.hgtags
9494cb0dc308d91ecae8514a341c2fa2324d3ade first
PS D:\tagstest [default tip]> hg update first
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 1 files removed, 0 files unresolved
PS D:\tagstest [default first]> cat .\.hgtags
cat : Cannot find path 'D:\tagstest\.hgtags' because it does not exist.
```

This case is just what you described in your question. But let's go further and add another tag:

```
PS D:\tagstest [default first]> hg up tip
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
PS D:\tagstest [default tip]> echo 'Something else' >> .\readme.txt
PS D:\tagstest [default ~1 tip]> hg ci -m "second commit"
PS D:\tagstest [default tip]> hg tag second
PS D:\tagstest [default tip]> cat .\.hgtags
9494cb0dc308d91ecae8514a341c2fa2324d3ade first
8b0455fffb17c978ef9e285905d76e34feae32f4 second
PS D:\tagstest [default tip]> hg up second
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
PS D:\tagstest [default second]> cat .\.hgtags
9494cb0dc308d91ecae8514a341c2fa2324d3ade first
```

Here you can see that after updating repository state to second tag `.hgtags` file didn't dissapear, but there's just first tag because the state of repository is just before second tag was added to `.hgtags` file.

**Update:**

In your case it looks like that you've added first tag `stable` (that caused creation of .hgtags file) to revision `0d80b6ba4ba3b51a44f0f1d339fcac1d4b21f387` after revision `c70d8e7e516d8b9e0c520063a575b4acea1b2f94` was created (that you tagged with `testtag`). So when you update repository state to `testtag` revision, there's no `.hgtags` file because it hasn't been created yet.

Example:

```
PS D:\tagstest2> hg init
PS D:\tagstest2 [default tip]> echo "Something" > readme.txt
PS D:\tagstest2 [default ?1 tip]> hg addremove
adding readme.txt
PS D:\tagstest2 [default +1 tip]> hg ci -m "First commit"
PS D:\tagstest2 [default tip]> echo "Something else" > .\readme.txt
PS D:\tagstest2 [default ~1 tip]> hg ci -m "Second commit"
PS D:\tagstest2 [default tip]> echo "Something more" >> .\readme.txt
PS D:\tagstest2 [default ~1 tip]> hg ci -m "Third commit"
PS D:\tagstest2 [default tip]> hg tag -r 0 first
PS D:\tagstest2 [default tip]> hg tag -r 1 second
PS D:\tagstest2 [default tip]> hg gl
@  4[tip]   a0753742f012   2013-08-21 00:29 +0400   peshkovroman
|    Added tag second for changeset 7e4896c8ef3e
|
o  3   cee5760a9d1c   2013-08-21 00:29 +0400   peshkovroman
|    Added tag first for changeset 12f055c90ee8
|
o  2   f4c00a7394e1   2013-08-21 00:29 +0400   peshkovroman
|    Third commit
|
o  1[second]   7e4896c8ef3e   2013-08-21 00:28 +0400   peshkovroman
|    Second commit
|
o  0[first]   12f055c90ee8   2013-08-21 00:28 +0400   peshkovroman
```

When you call `hg up second`, your repository state will be updated to revision 1, but `.hgtags` was created only in revision 2.